# Fluorescent light turns off randomly?

Tags: lighting

I have a simple two bulb fluorescent shop light, and it will shut off out of nowhere. If I unplug it and plug it back in it will come back on. But it doesn't do this all the time, sometimes it qil stay on for days without shutting off. Is it possibly a exposed wire grounding out? I feel if the ballast was out it would be more consistent. Just seems to always go out at just the not so perfect moment. There's nothing else on that circuit. Im confident I could take it apart but im just need to know what im looking for. Ty for your time.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Try wiggling the cord while it is lit. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Answer (score 2):

The internals are pretty straightforward.  You're just looking for loose wires in connections, loose wires at a tombstone, etc.

While you're in there, size up the wiring.  If there are 2 wires to every end of every lamp, that takes a different ballast than if there is only one.  Ballast swaps aren't too bad and they are also an opportunity to upgrade to T8 lighting.

You could also think about going LED if the fix does not prove to be easy.  Get direct-wire aka ballast-bypass LEDs, don't get plug-n-play/needs-ballast LEDs.

Comment: Also ballasts have a thermal overload on them that sometimes go bad and create the problem you are having. Upgrading the ballast or going to LED is always a good idea.